# customizing map overlays in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, overlay, customization

I have a mapView with 2 circles. When I try to customize the large one the small one seems to follow the large one. For example if I customize the fill color for the large one the smaller one gets the same color. How do I make the smaller one a different color? Note: I use reusable identifiers. Thank you.. this is my working code but when i try to edit my smaller circle, the one with radius 100 it doesn't. note: this is my WORKING code as anything else i tried it failed.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
static NSString *CircleOverlayIdentifier = @"Circle";

_mapView.delegate = self;

if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[CircleOverlay class]]) {
    CircleOverlay *circleOverlay = (CircleOverlay *)overlay;

    MKCircleView *annotationView =
    (MKCircleView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:CircleOverlayIdentifier];

    if (!annotationView) {
        MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle
                            circleWithCenterCoordinate:circleOverlay.coordinate
                            radius:circleOverlay.radius];
        annotationView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:circle];
        //this one

    }


    if (overlay == self.targetOverlay) {
        //adjustable
        annotationView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.3f];
        annotationView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        annotationView.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    } else {
        //fixed
        annotationView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3f alpha:0.3f];
        annotationView.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        annotationView.lineWidth = 2.0f;


    }

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
}

- (void)configureOverlay {
if (self.location) {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];        
    [self.mapView removeOverlays:[self.mapView overlays]];


    CircleOverlay *overlaysmall = [[CircleOverlay alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:100];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlaysmall];

    _targetOverlaySmall = overlaysmall;

    CircleOverlay *overlay = [[CircleOverlay alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay];

    GeoQueryAnnotation *annotation = [[GeoQueryAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    [self updateLocations];
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to share some code with us.

Comment: You're missing some vital code there. Where does targetOverlay get set? If it is never set "overlay == self.targetOverlay" will always be false and you'll set every overlay to purple.